# How to get path to Linux installation from within WSL in Fall Creators Update

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-subsystem-for-linux

Before the recent update WSL root filesystem was always in `C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Local\lxss`, but now when Linux is installed from the App Store it can be different for each installation. For example for Ubuntu on my machine it is `C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Local\Packages\CanonicalGroupLimited.UbuntuonWindows_79rhkp1fndgsc\LocalState\rootfs`

Is there a way to detect this path from within current WSL session?

Answer (score 3):

As noted by other users, nowadays you can install multiple Linux distributions and each distribution have their own filesystem located in a different folder. The location of each filesystem can be obtained from the Windows Registry.

You can run `regedit` and look for the information. The data is located under

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Lxss
```

In addition, you can start a PowerShell window and execute the following command to determine information of all the installed Linux distributions.

```
(Get-ChildItem "HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Lxss" -Recurse)
```

To obtain the location of the filesystems, you can run

```
(Get-ChildItem HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Lxss | ForEach-Object {Get-ItemProperty $_.PSPath}) | select DistributionName,BasePath
```

Answer (score 0):

In PowerShell:

```
> echo ($env:LOCALAPPDATA + '\Packages\' + ($(get-appxpackage).PackageFamilyName|findstr UbuntuonWindows))
C:\Users\Reker\AppData\Local\Packages\CanonicalGroupLimited.UbuntuonWindows_79rhkp1fndgsc
```

You can run above command in bash.exe on Windows 14393 or above by interop with windows cmd.exe or powershell.exe

Comment: What if there are multiple Linux distributions installed. How do I detect it for the current one?

Comment: Get current distro name, then read keys inside  HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Lxss\